# Show values in dropdown list in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I want to add documents about different parts of my facility in my Django app.
So, I have the following models in my models.py:

```
class Parts(models.Model):
   Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
class Docs(models.Model):
   Date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
   Type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   Part = models.ForeignKey(Parts)
   Link = models.FileField(upload_to='Docs/%Y/%m/%d')
```

forms.py:

```
class DocsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Docs
        fields = ['Date', 'Type', 'Part', 'Link']
class PartsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Parts
        fields = ['Name']
```

views.py:

```
def adddocs(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    f = DocsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if f.is_valid():
        f.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('')
else:
    form = DocsForm() 
return render(
    request,
    'adddocs.html',
    {'form': form}
```

and the following fragment in my template:

```
 <form action="{% url 'adddocs' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           {% csrf_token %}
            <p> {{form.Date}}  </p>
            <p> {{form.Type}}  </p>
            <p> {{form.Part}}  </p>
            <p> {{form.Link}}  </p>

            <p><input type="submit" value="Add" /></p>
                </form>
```

And everything works fine except one problem. Now I have two parts of my facility, for example 'tubes' and 'storage'. But if I want to choose them in dropdown list, I see the following variants in my browser:

---

Parts Object
Parts Object

**What should I change to see names of parts like this**

---

tubes
 storage
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [**str**()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.__str__) method in your Models.

> The **str**() method is called whenever you call str() on an object. Django uses str(obj) in a number of places. Most notably, to display an object in the Django admin site and as the value inserted into a template when it displays an object. Thus, you should always return a nice, human-readable representation of the model from the **str**() method.

```
class Parts(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    # call to return name 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```